# Is the sentence "are you done your soup?" proper English?

Tags: word-usage

My mother in law is Scottish and has lived in Canada for the last 45 years.  She will often omit the word "with."  When asking my child if he is ready to get out of the bathtub she will say "Henry, are you done your bath?" or before clearing his plate she will say "are you done your dinner?"  She has excellent vocabulary and grammar, so this struck me as very odd.

Is this usage proper?  If so, where is this usage common?

Comment: There are 250 000 results on Google for "are done your bath". Or perhaps just 12, including quite a few repeats. I'd say it is highly colloquial, and probably of a Scottish register, as you imply. Have you the courage to ask _her_? She'll appreciate the academic nature of your request as someone blessed with excellent vocabulary and grammar.

Comment: I've asked her, but she didn't have much of an explanation.  My wife uses the same phrasing.  [This forum post](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1228954) suggests leaving out the preposition is a common informal speech pattern in Canada.

Comment: @Abernasty: Good catch!

Comment: ... Sensational catch.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be Canadian. In Scotland, one would look at the chicken on your plate and say to you, "is that you?" ! :-)

I have found at least two references to this expression on the web, the first one refers to an American asking why her Canadian girlfriend speaks this way. The second has an answer which asks if the speaker is Canadian (or nearby.)

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1228954
and
http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/1253159

Comment: I'm assuming it's not *frowned upon* to reference *rival* QA forums :-)

Comment: It's done all the time, don't worry!

Comment: Given the area throughout which this is apparently a quite unremarkable construction, I am frankly flabbergasted that I have _never_, in my entire life, heard it at all. It sounds so bizarre and ungrammatical to me that I doubt I would even have known what was meant by it, even in context, if the asker hadn't explained. Truly surprising.

Answer (score -3):

Lowland Scottish is a language, very similar to English, but sufficiently different to be regarded as a separate tongue. (Highland Scots is Gaelic, and quite different). I am no expert on the Scottish standard, but my guess is that that is what your mother-in-law was taught at school and by her parents.

Comment: Firstly I must ask if you are referring to Lowland Scots, rather than *Lowland Scottish*. Secondly, it's more a political matter than linguistic as to whether it's a separate tongue. What's true is that Scots speak in a dialect continuum between old braid Scots and Standard English. Again, at least in Scotland, original speech of the Highlanders is called Scottish Gaelic, rather than Highland Scots.

Comment: I knew that one was Scots and the other Scottish. It appears I got them the wrong way round. I apologise if this has caused offence!

Comment: Well, no offence caused, but technically, there is no language called *Scottish*.